# How to: Copy Images from Gnome to public_html on same server

Tags: centos, filenames, cp

Hi there I am using CentOS7 as server + GUI.  I want to move pictures from Gnome to a public_html directory.  What is wrong with my command?

```
cp -R ~orca/Documents/Tree\ of\ Knowledge/oceanahomes.com/393\ Hastings/Pictures/ /var/www/oceanahomes.org/public_html/393 

cp: cannot stat ‘/home/orca/Documents/Tree of Knowledge/oceanahomes.com/393 Hastings/Pictures/’: No such file or directory
```

On the terminal I am logged in as orca user.  I can su

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

This works.

```
cp -R /home/orca/Documents/Tree\ Of\ Knowledge/oceanahomes.com/393\ Hastings/Pictures/ /var/www/oceanahomes.org/public_html/393
```

Comment: What was the fix, then? If it turns out that you simply had a typo in the file `of` vs `Of`, then this is not a question or answer that will help others. At any rate, explaining ***why*** a command works to answer the question is imperative.

Comment: ~orca/ versus /home/orca was the material difference to me. I acknowledge explaining why in the future.

Comment: @JesseWilliamMacDougall I'm not convinced of that being the critical difference, since the question's error message says "cp: cannot stat ‘/home/orca/Documents ..." meaning it successfully expanded `~orca` to `/home/orca`.

Comment: The material difference in *what you posted* was a typo in `Of`. So, either you didn't post the actual command that worked in your answer, or you haven't noticed the typo yet.